# Difference in speed while accessing an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, performance

**Is any difference (in speed of my program - execution time) between??**

**1 st option:**

```
 private void particleReInit(int loop)
        {
            this.particle[loop].active = true;
            this.particle[loop].life = 1.0f;
            this.particle[loop].fade = 0.3f * (float)(this.random.Next(100)) / 1000.0f + 0.003f; 
            this.particle[loop].r = colors[this.col][0];    // Select Red Rainbow Color
            this.particle[loop].g = colors[this.col][1];    // Select Red Rainbow Color
            this.particle[loop].b = colors[this.col][2];    // Select Red Rainbow Color
            this.particle[loop].x = 0.0f;
            this.particle[loop].y = 0.0f;
            this.particle[loop].xi = 10.0f * (this.random.Next(120) - 60.0f);
            this.particle[loop].yi = (-50.0f) * (this.random.Next(60)) - (30.0f);
            this.particle[loop].xg = 0.0f; 
            this.particle[loop].yg = 0.8f; 
            this.particle[loop].size = 0.2f;
            this.particle[loop].center = new PointF(particleTextures[0].Width / 2, particleTextures[0].Height / 2);

    }
```

**2 nd option:**

```
Particle p = particle[loop];
p.active = true;
p.life = 1.0f;
...
```

Where `Particle particle[] = new Particle[NumberOfParticles];` is just an array of Particles which have some properties like life, position.

I'm doing it in Visual Studio 2010 Like WFA (Windows Form Aplication) and need to enhance performance (we're not able to use OpenGL, so for more particles my program tends to be slow).

Comment: You could easily test this out yourself by doing it in a loop a billion times. I would think that the difference, if any, would be very, very minute.

Comment: In the second option you do not have to use the index accesor of the array every time you change the particle. I can't say for sure if this will improve performance but it also makes for better reading.

Comment: Except by accessing `this.particle[loop].PropertyName` aren't you forcing an index search of the array for every property?  I'd think caching the reference in the 2nd option would be the best way.  But, you don't know unless you run a quick test.

Comment: Is this a "dependecey encapsulation" approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would certainly expect there to be a difference in speed - it's doing more work, after all. Another thread may have changed the contents of the array between statements, which *may* (or may not) be visible within this thread. If these are properties rather than fields, the property setter could even conceivably change the values in the array within the *same* thread, which would *have* to be visible.

Whether the difference in speed is *significant* or not is a different matter, and one that we can't judge.

More importantly, I'd say that the second form is *clearer* than the existing code.

In fact, if this is actually meant to be reinitializing the whole element, I'd actually create a *new* `Particle` and then assign that to the element:

```
particle[loop] = new Particle {
    active = true,
    life = 1f,
    // etc
};
```

... or create a separate method/constructor which created a particle in an appropriate state.

Comment: Does the constructor have a performance advantage to go with the obvious contextual/readability improvement?

Comment: Thank's, it's exactly what I needed to know. Also the comments what is clearer helps cause I really don't expect that this will have big influence on performance but I wanted to do better code :) There are many places where I can improve the performance. I first tryed to make it work somehow and now I´m cleaning the code ..

Comment: @Jodrell - there's no performance advantage, C# compiler translates these as standard field/property assignments - generated IL code is identical

Answer (score 2):

While there is likely to be a very small difference in speed, any difference in speed here is likely going to be negligible.  I would use the version that is the easiest to read and maintain.

Personally, I prefer your 2nd option, as I find it much easier to read.

> I'm doing it in Visual Studio 2010 Like WFA (Windows Form Aplication) and need to enhance performance (we're not able to use OpenGL .. so for more particles my program tends to be slow).

If your goal is performance, I highly doubt this routine is the core of your problem.  You should run this under a profiler.  Until you actually *measure your performance*, and find the real problem, you're just guessing and likely going to spend time optimizing the wrong thing.

It is far more likely that the rendering of the "particles" using GDI+ is likely more of a bottleneck, and changing this routine between your two options will have no impact on the perceived speed.

Comment: I wanted to improve performance but I don't expect big difference. I'm cleaning my code and also want it work quicker. It was first and easiest thing to change. Now I'm gonna improve calculating new positions and rendering.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative - make Particle a struct, initialize it sequentially in loop and I bet it will be much faster as any of these 2 options.

Comment: I don't know why but I think that from some really important reason should be Particle a class.

Comment: There could be lots of reasons to use class for Particle, but if your goal is to get better performance - using stuct would be much faster (though you may need to tune your code a little as struct is value type).